# Text in front of CSS shape

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get text to be on top (or in front of) a CSS shape. It works with `border-bottom`, but not with `border-top` (which is what I need it to look like).
I am assuming that because the `border-top` property is set that it's pushing the text below the shape.

Not too sure how to get it to work correctly without having to use an image. I could have swore I've seen this done before, but I can't remember where.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/W2SPd/

```
<h1>the trap</h1>
```

```
h1 {
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert a `span` tag for the text and get:

```
h1 {
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
h1 span {
   position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/W2SPd/10/

Feasible?

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 elements and 2 CSS styles. One for the text, and one for the background:

```
<h1><div>the trap</div></h1>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
h1 div {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vPt7h/

Comment: I tried to nestle that into a span tag but I wasn't using a negative for the top value. But your's and the other above works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a new pseudo element `:after` and then style the pseudo element with the border styles instead :)

The advantages? You don't have to create new elements just for the style alone, or use unnecessary nesting/wrapping with no semantic meaning; and it is not an image-based solution. The drawback - requires browser support for pseudo elements, so may not work on old versions of IE... but that's not something you should worry about.

```
h1 {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 50px; /* To account for the left and right borders in pseudo element to ensure it lines up */
}
h1:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    z-index: -1; /* Displays pseudo element behind text */
    width: 100px;
}
```

See fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/W2SPd/11/

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Yeah, I was trying to get it to work with :after, but I must have been missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's really a bad way to do it imo. It will still take up more space than needed and you're asking for potential problems down the road. Yes you can use the examples others have provided but if it were me, I would make the shape an image and use it as a background via CSS.

```
.myShape { background:url(/pathto/your/image.png); width:150px; height:100px; }
```

Comment: or even a sprite border. Though it wouldn't be as reliable as background, it would give you more flexibility.

Comment: *"Not too sure how to get it to work correctly without having to use an image."* - OP

Comment: I can imagine several reasons why one might not want to use images. They require a separate request, are more difficult to change the color dynamically, etc.

Comment: @DJDavid98 technically, it's a background, not an image. `<img>` is an image, and would indeed be clunky.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I agree, but there are ways to make it editable without a physical 'image', like .svg images, for example. Negative margins have gotten me into trouble, so I consider them bad practice.

Comment: @kcdwayne Funny logic there. The background IS an image. Not sure what you're getting at.